# Printing the content of a file

Tags: c, string, realloc

```
openFile(argv[1],"r");
while(characterBuff != EOF)
{
    characterBuff = fgetc(examFile);
    memoryAlloc += 1;
    string = expandRealloc(string, memoryAlloc);
    appendString(string, characterBuff);
    printf("%s\n", string);
}
closeFile();
free(string);
```

In the following code: The output I'm getting from printf gives me ackward values like [somehash]D[somehash]E[somehash]S[somehash]K

I'm getting the output word which is "DESK" but with all kind of random stuff taken from the memory, what Am I doing wrong?

Note: The following has been allocated with malloc(sizeof(char)) and realocates every time a single char is added to the string.

I.e the output I should be getting should be:
D
De
Des
Desk
But instead of that I'm getting the thing i shown u before.

EDIT:

```
char* expandRealloc(char* ptrS, size_t n)
{
    void *tmp;
    if((tmp = realloc(ptrS, n)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Memory leak possible; Closing Program");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        ptrS = tmp;
        return ptrS;
    }
}
```

I Wrote a wrapper function for realloc. Thank for the help, but it still doesnt solve the problem, i still get [somecrapmemoryhash][letter][somecrapmemoryhash][letter] when trying to printf the result.

APPEND STRING:

```
void appendString(char* inputString, int inputChar)
{
    int stringLenght = strlen(inputString);
    inputString[stringLenght - 1] = inputChar;
    inputString[stringLenght] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: I suppose this is C/C++?

Comment: One big problem to start with - your call to realloc is broken - look at the man page for realloc

Comment: What amout a [minimal example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: You might need to post the code for `appendString`

Answer (score 4):

When `realloc` is called, it may move the allocated memory and so you need to replace the old contents of your pointer with the value returned by realloc.

Try

```
char *temp_string;
    .
    .
    .
temp_string = realloc(string, memoryAlloc);
if(temp_string != NULL)
  string = temp_string;
```

---

**EDIT**

It strikes me that much of the problem here is the use of user-written functions to do things which have long been part of the standard library. Modifying this code to use standard lib functions without the use of special wrappers, etc, would be no more difficult and would result in greater reliability. As an example, the appendString function seems to have been the source of much of the difficulties encountered here. If the strcat function had been used instead (with minor mods to the source) a great deal of aggravation and hair-pulling could have been avoided.

The standard library is there for excellent reasons. It's consistent, solid, debugged, useful, and - well - it's the STANDARD. If anyone here thinks that they, by themselves, are smarter than the hundreds of people who have contributed to the standard lib, they are very likely wrong. If someone here thinks that they can't POSSIBLY use functions from the standard library to perform basic operations because their needs are so incredibly special, they are very likely wrong. The C language, by itself, is not particularly special - let's face it, curly braces are not such a big deal :-) - the power of C comes directly from the philosophy of "put everything in a function" - i.e. from the use of libraries of functions to accomplish tasks. The standard library is the most basic thing that beginning C programmers need to learn, and its use should be second nature to any experienced C programmer.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: This results in a memory leak though if realloc fails (i.e. returns NULL) - you should assign the result of realloc to a temporary pointer first.

Comment: Wrote a wrapper function for realloc, and modified it, but it still doesnt solve the problem with printing, which is the bugger for me. For the content of the code reffer to the first post.

Comment: @PiotrJerzyMamenas - could you add the code for your `appendString` procedure to the original post?

Answer (score 2):

Your `appendString` function is wrong - change:

```
void appendString(char* inputString, int inputChar)
{
    int stringLenght = strlen(inputString);
    inputString[stringLenght - 1] = inputChar;
    inputString[stringLenght] = '\0';
}
```

to:

```
void appendString(char* inputString, int inputChar)
{
    int stringLength = strlen(inputString);
    inputString[stringLength] = inputChar;
    inputString[stringLength + 1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: And I still get the [weirdmemoryhashes] at the start of the string

Comment: How are you initialising `string` in the first place ? You mighht need to post the code for this part too.

Answer (score 0):

Your string printing problem looks suspiciously like a lack of `NULL` termination on the end of your string... does `appendString` take care of adding the terminator?

Comment: Yes, it adds a terminator. Note that my problem is not printing: DESKfo0932jfjewf98wjef98wejf etc but D[Psunflowersign]E[Psunflowersign] etc